# Address Not Getting Stored Correctly in State Variable?

Tags: contract-design, addresses, storage, data-types, access

I am trying to write a contract where the originator of the contract will offer a reward that can only be claimed by a different address that she or he specifies.  To do that, I am trying to create state variable of type 'address' that stores the address of the person who is allowed to claim the reward, which I am calling the 'ambassador'.

See the code below:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;    
contract AmbassadorTask {
    address private owner; // Address of business offering rewards for a task 
    uint taskReward; // How much ether ambassadors get every time they complete a task
    address ambassador; // Represents person allowed to complete task and claim rewards

    //Constructor
    function AmbassadorTask (address _ambassador) public payable {
            require (msg.value > 0); // No point creating tasks with no rewards
            owner = msg.sender;  // Set creator to be the owner of this contract
            taskReward = msg.value;
            ambassador = _ambassador;
    }

    function getAmbassador() public view returns (address _ambassador) {
        return ambassador;
    }
}
```

The code compiles correctly in Remix, but when I test it at run time using the JavaScriptVM, the 'ambassador' address that is stored in the contract is not the same address that I pass as input in the constructor.

For example, I pass 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c as input, when calling the constructor.  If I immediately call getAmbassador(), I get the following output: 0xa4aff308fddc160c000000000000000000000000, instead of the value I entered to create the contract.  I also noticed that it is just the last 16 hex digits from the address I passed, followed by trailing zeros.

In contrast, I am not having the same issue storing msg.sender to the owner state variable when I call the constructor.

Why is this happening?  I am storing the address values incorrectly?  Is this a data conversion issue?

Thanks in advanced for your help!

Comment: Thanks for checking!  I wonder if it might help to pass the address as a string and then convert it to address during the constructor, just to have a work around.  Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you put quotes around the address when specifying it as a constructor parameter. Remix does a very poor job of parsing unquoted hexadecimal strings.

I could reproduce the behavior you saw only by using an unquoted hexadecimal string. With quotes, it worked correctly all 10 times I attempted it.

Comment: Yup!!! That did it.  Thank you so much.  I can't believe it was just a matter of missing quotes.  Thank you very much for your help!